# Day click event on fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, click, fullcalendar

How can I achieve a day click event on [***`fullcalendar`***](https://fullcalendar.io/)?

What I want to achieve is to show a day on a click event as in: to show the specific date clicked as in: the 9<sup>th</sup> or 10<sup>th</sup> of a given month based on the appropriate click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the docs: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        if (allDay) {
            alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
        }else{
            alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
        }

        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

    }
});
```